# A little trouble with creating a single linked list in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am going to create a single linked list and construct a function (Locate()) that returns the address of the element.But in the end, I didn't see the result of this function. I tried it. This function should be run, but the result is different from what I expected.

use vs2019 on WIndows10，a student:)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node {                           //Node
    int data;
    Node* link;
    Node(int item, Node* l = NULL)
    {
        data = item;
        link = l;
    }
    Node(Node* l = NULL)
    {
        data = 0;
        link = l;
    }
};

class Link :public Node {        //Link
private:
    Node* first;
public:
    Link(Node* l = NULL)
    {
        first = l;
    }
    Link(int d, Node* l = NULL)
    {
        first = new Node(d);
    }
    Node* Locate(int i);
};
Node* Link::Locate(int i)       //Locate()
{
    if (i < 0)
    {
        cerr << "wrong operation when locating" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    int count = 0;
    Node* current = first;
    while (count < i && current->link != NULL)
    {
        current = current->link;
        count++;
    }
    return current;
}
int main()
{
    Link a;
    Node* b = new Node(1);
    Node* c = new Node(2);
    a.link = b;
    b->link = c;
    cout << a.data << ' ' << b->data << ' '<<c->data<<endl;
    cout << a.Locate(1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Will not output the result of this function 'Locate()' being called

Answer (score 0):

`Locate()` accesses `first->link`. At that time, `first` is a null pointer. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior; in practice, it most likely crashes.

Answer (score 0):

When I re-modify the List constructor, its(Locate()) output is normal and the expected result is obtained.
The modified constructors are as follows:

```
Link()
    {
        first = new Node;
    }
    Link(int d)
    {
        first = new Node(d);
    }
    Node* Locate(int i);
```